# php curl error : Couldn't resolve host

Tags: php, curl

Hi i am trying to send sms through my sms api it used to work fine before but when i changed my api link it started giving me error 
here is my code

```
$url = "http://vas.mobilogi.com/api.php?";

$message = urlencode($message);
$ch = curl_init();

if (!$ch) {
    die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");
}

$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=$user&password=$password&sender=$senderid&to=$mobilenumbers&message=$message&response='Y'&unicode='Y'");
```

Comment: Try it with out the two SSL options - that url doesn't appear to have a https version.

Comment: Also if it actually should be ssl for god's sake stop using `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false`.